# How can I merge three similar methods with different argument types into one generic one?

Tags: java, generics

I am relatively inexperienced with java & generics, so please excuse me if this is a stupid question.

I have 3 very similar helper methods called verifyTextualSort, verifyNumericSort and verifyDateSort.

The 3 methods follow the same pattern with only a slight difference in them:

```
private boolean verifyTextualSort(...) {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Do common stuff with the list

    // Do textual-specific stuff 

    // Do common stuff with the list

}

private boolean verifyNumericSort(...) {

    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Do common stuff with the list

    // Do Numeric-specific stuff

    // Do common stuff with the list

}
```

Is there some way I can combine them into one method, passing somehow the type (Integer, String, Date) as a parameter? I have to be able to know which is the type from inside the method so that I can do the correct specific stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by "textual-specific" and "numeric-specific"?

Comment: I meant processing that is not common for the 3 methods

Comment: The sensible answer depends to quite some extent on how similar the "textual-specific" and "Numeric-specific" bits are, how big they are, and what dependencies they have.  In the best case it would be trivial to combine them, in the worst case it makes sense to have two different methods anyway.  Beyond that, you should factor out the common stuff as per Peter Lawrey's answer.

Comment: The specific bits are very small (1-2 lines of code), on the other hand the common bits are also not big basically just a loop that reads data and adds it to the list. The reading part is different. And at the end I use the Java Collections framework to find out if my lists are sorted or not.

Comment: @VAA: "I meant processing that is not common for the 3 methods" If they are not common then you cannot use Generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a `Class` as a parameter, if that is what you want (as you said, passing the type as a parameter):

```
public <T> void test(List<T> l, T t, Class<T> c) {
    System.out.println(c.getName());
    System.out.println(l.get(0).getClass().getName());
    System.out.println(t.getClass().getName());
}
```

All the sysouts above will print out the name of the class, so you'll be able to choose which one suits you the best.

Comment: I added a type parameter to the Class object - this makes sure that the caller will actually pass the class object belonging to the type parameter of the list.

Comment: Also, while the `getClass()` approach might work for the types mentioned in the question, it if fails if there can by objects of subclasses of the list element type in the list (like a `List<Number>`, which contains `Integer`, `Double`, and `BigDecimal` objects).

Answer (score 4):

You need three method for the specific stuff. However for the common stuff you can create a common method they both call.

```
private boolean verifyNumericSort(...) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    commonStuff1(list);

    // Do Numeric-specific stuff

    commonStuff2(list);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but actually this is not that useful in my case as both the common and the specific things are just 1-2 lines of code (as I commented before, the common stuff is basically just a loop around the specific stuff)

Comment: So you are saying that most of the important code is method specific, i.e. there is not much in common between methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that by introspection using the Generics because of [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). But if the list is not empty, you can check the type of the first element and then invoke appropriate method.

Answer (score 0):

since you have 3 fields you can do this..

```
class A
{
private Date date = null;
private Integer int = null;
private String text = null;

//add getters and setters for these fields
}
```

and now pass this class Object as an arguement to that method

```
public boolean verify(A a){
a.getDate();
a.getInt()
//etc and do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need generics and refactoring:

```
private boolean verifyTextualSort(List<String> strings) {
    commonStuffA(strings);
    // Do textual-specific stuff
    commonStuffB(strings);
    return true; // ?
}

private boolean verifyNumericSort(List<Integer> ints) {
    commonStuffB(ints);
    // Do Numeric-specific stuff
    commonStuffB(ints);
    return true; // ?
}

private void commonStuffA(List<?> things) { // This method accept a list of anything
    // Do common stuff A with the list
}

private void commonStuffB(List<?> things) { // This method accept a list of anything
    // Do common stuff B with the list
}

private void someCallingMethod() {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    verifyTextualSort(strings);

    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    verifyTextualSort(ints);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could possibly do something similar to this:

```
  public <T extends Object> boolean verify(T t)
  {
    if(!(t==null))
    {
      if(t instanceof Date)
      {
        //Do date verify routine
        return true;
      }
      else if(t instanceof String)
      {
        //Do String verify routine
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        //Do default verify routine which could be Integer
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

**NOTE:**
This is not tested.

Comment: that's the same as `public boolean verify(Object t)`. generics has no use in your code

Comment: It doesn't need to - the question is asking to combine three types namely, `Date, String and Integer` why waste time doing `.getClass().getName()` when in effect could be tackled pretty simply by doing it this way - easy for whoever is going to read the code on the authors absence to dive straight in.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you can't do that with generics because of type erasure (see the other answers for a link to type erasure).  I believe you can get a reasonable solution (without *instanceof*) with *polymorphism*.  Here is an example:

```
public class VerifySort
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        VerifySort verifySort = new VerifySort();

        Date testDate = new Date();
        Integer testInteger = 17;
        String testString = "Blammy";

        verifySort.verify(testString);
        verifySort.verify(testInteger);
        verifySort.verify(testDate);
    }

    private boolean verify(Date parameter)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
        System.out.print("Date parameter: ");
        System.out.println(dateFormat.format(parameter));

        return true;
    }

    private boolean verify(Integer parameter)
    {
        System.out.print("Integer parameter: ");
        System.out.println(parameter);

        return true;
    }

    private boolean verify(String parameter)
    {
        System.out.print("String parameter: ");
        System.out.println(parameter);

        return true;
    }
```